# Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]: に関して

Tags: apache, fuelphp

今httpd.confやhttpd-vhosts.confの設定をし、
Apache Web Serverを再起動して、あるページにアクセスしようとすると、
下記エラーが出ました。

```
Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]:
    Unable to create or write to the log file. Please check the permissions on /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/fuel/manage/logs/. (mkdir(): Permission denied)

COREPATH/classes/log.php @ line 77
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/■■■■/fuel/core/classes/log.php

    throw new \FuelException('Unable to create or write to the log file. Please check the permissions on '.\Config::get('log_path').'. ('.$e->getMessage().')');
```

エラー日本語訳

```
ログファイルを作成または書き込めません。 / Applications / XAMPP / xamppfiles / htdocs / ■■■■ / fuel / manage / logs /の権限を確認してください。 （mkdir（）：許可が拒否されました）
```

とあるので確認すると/ Applications / XAMPP / xamppfiles / htdocs / ■■■■ / fuel / manage /まではありますが、logs /がありません。

COREPATH/classes/log.php @ line 77を見ても何が間違っているのかが不明です。
FuelPHPの画面が出てくるのも含めて不明です。

どなたか私にご助言を下さいませんか。
他に必要な情報があればご提供します。
宜しくお願いします。

```
DocumentRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"

port 8080
```

Comment: logsというディレクトリを作るとどうなりますか？

Comment: / Applications / XAMPP / xamppfiles / htdocs / ■■■■ / fuel / manage /の後に、logsのディレクトリを作り再度、同じURLを打ち込みましたが、同じエラー画面になります。

Comment: 「権限を確認してください」とあるのでlogsディレクトリの権限情報を追記してください

Comment: logsのアクセス権ですが自分,staff,everyoneを全て読み/書きにして再度試すと、Fuel\Core\FuelException [ Error ]:
The webserver doesn't have write access to the path to store the session data files.
COREPATH/classes/session/file.php @ line 341                               throw new \FuelException('The webserver doesn\'t have write access to the path to store the session data files.');が表示されました

Comment: 別のエラーが出たということは、既存のエラーは解決したのですね。でしたら自己回答してください。新しいエラーについては調査修正をしてみて、もしわからなければ、また新しく質問してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自己回答して、新しいエラーに関しては調査してわからなければ新たに質問をします。

Answer (score 1):

今回は、logsというフォルダを作成して、アクセス権を読み/書きにするとlogs/2018/08/20.phpというファイルが作られエラー解決となりました。
宜しくお願いします。